# Cutting holes in custom polygon made with Leaflet.Draw

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, mapbox, leaflet-draw, leaflet-plugins

I would like to be able to create holes in polygons made with Leaflet.Draw plugin. For example, I currently have code like this: https://jsfiddle.net/4gkrfu5b/

If you draw a polygon on top of another polygon, there will be two polygons overlapping each other. I would like to get an effect, similar to this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/bnue5tjg/5/

The second example nicely implements the cutout possibility with polygon drawn on top of another polygon. The only downside it has, it is made with one existing polygon pre-rendered on the map. I prefer to start with a clean workspace and then be able to create polygons and holes in them. I have tried to implement the second example into my code, but for now I have been unsuccessful with this. Any help with cutouts implementation will be welcome. Hope that the stackexchange community can help me with implementation of cutouts / holes on polygons we make on the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility of doing this would be with the help of [turf.js](https://turfjs.org/) library.

When adding newly drawn polygon, algorithm for detecting and creating possible holes goes like this:

1. Convert newly created layer/polygon to GeoJSON and then to turf geometry.
2. Iterate through all existing layers/polygons.
3. Convert each layer/polygon to turf geometry and check if it contains newly created polygon.
4. If it contains newly created polygon, drill hole in it with with `turf.difference` method
5. Remove old polygon without one hole.
6. Add new polygon.

Here is the code:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  var geojson;
  var geom;
  var newGeom;
  var newLayer;

  var newLayer = e.layer;
  var newGeom = turf.getGeom(newLayer.toGeoJSON());

  drawnItems.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    geojson = layer.toGeoJSON();
    if (geojson.type == 'FeatureCollection') {
      geojson = geojson.features[0];
    }
    geom = turf.getGeom(geojson);
    if (turf.booleanContains(geom, newGeom)) {
      newGeom = turf.difference(geom, newGeom);
      newLayer = L.geoJSON(newGeom);
      drawnItems.removeLayer(layer);
    }
  });
  drawnItems.addLayer(newLayer);
});
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. JSFiddle of working solution: https://jsfiddle.net/bmkn7axq/1/

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me!

```
        //making a hole in global_mask json layer using key_state json
        key_state_json.geometry.coordinates.forEach(element => {
            if (key_state_json.geometry.type == 'Polygon') {
                var polygon = element;
                global_mask_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push(polygon);
            } else if (key_state_json.geometry.type == 'MultiPolygon') {
                Object.values(element).forEach(polygon => {
                    global_mask_json.features[0].geometry.coordinates.push(polygon);
                });
            }
        });
```